# command fails when fed argument via xargs, but not when fed the argument directly

Tags: bash, xargs

I have a bash function

```
agg_generror () {
    echo $1
    find ${folder} -name "${prefix}_*_${1}_${suffix}.count" | xargs -I % sh -c 'cat %; echo "";' | awk 'BEGIN{e=0;t=0} {e+=$1;t+=$2} END{print e/t}' > generror_${1}
}
```

which if I call directly

```
agg_generror 17.5
```

works and doesn't complain.

But if I do

```
echo 17.5 | xargs -I % sh -c 'agg_generror %'
```

It fails with

```
17.5
awk: fatal: division by zero attempted
```

Why may the behaviour different in the two cases?

Comment: Where do you set `$folder` and `$prefix` and `$suffix`?

Comment: You're starting a new shell with `sh -c`, so any shell variables set in the current shell will not be visible there, unless you export them as environment variables.

Comment: Ah, so that's what it is.. Thank you!
Yeah I was setting them outside the function

Answer (score 0):

while read; do agg_generror $REPLY; done < input.txt